# Inherit IO redirections from a script to another

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, io

When I redirect the output of a script within a script, I expect the redirection to be applied to the called script as well as the program called within it.

A:

```
./B 2>> error.log
```

B:

```
./executable
```

Running A outputs to `stdout` and `stderr`. I'd expect `stderr` to go to `error.log` instead. Apparently I am wrong.

Why isn't the output of B redirected, when called from A?

How can I make sure that the subscript's (B) and the executable's output are redirected as A is trying to attempt?

Here is my actual test case:

---

redir.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
./other_script.sh 2>> error.log
```

---

other_script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
./redirection
```

---

`redirection` compiled from `redirection.c` with `gcc -o redirection redirection.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NB_LOOPS (10)

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NB_LOOPS; ++i) {
        fprintf(stdout, "stdout %d\n", i);
        fprintf(stderr, "stderr %d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May be `source ./B 2>> error.log` in *A* helps

Comment: FWIW - It writes the "stderr n" lines` to `error.log` for me - using your compiled `c` program and scripts as per your examples.